# How to break primeng confirmation box message to separate line?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, element, primeng

Can anyone give me the suggestion to break the confirm box message.

I have tried this below code. but it's showing br tag as a string. Any other way to solve this?

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
                    message: 'CoC updated successfully' + '</br>' + ' Do you want to close or continue working with this?',
                    icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
                    header: 'Confirm Save',
                    accept: () => {
                       this.infomessage = [];
                        this.infomessage.push({ severity: 'success', summary: '', detail: Updated Successfully' });                    },
                    reject: () => {
                        this.router.navigate(['versions']);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: `<br/>` or `\n` ?

Comment: Both are tried. but unluckily not working

Comment: I don't have any idea about template string. I already post my code in question. I need couple of confirm box in am page. So I don't like to use with template.

Comment: I think it behaves like a JavaScript alert and doesn't allow HTML in it. There is actually an opened issue for using `innerHTML` instead of *interpolation binding*: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2116

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, I got it by the following steps.

### Step 1

We need move `{{message}}` to inside the `<pre>` tag in
`confirmdialog.metadata.json` file. like,

```
<span class=\"ui-confirmdialog-message\"><pre>{{message}}</pre></span>
```

### Step 2

And we should add `white-space: pre-line` in this class `.ui-confirmdialog-message`. like,

```
.ui-confirmdialog-message {
       white-space: pre-line;
}
```

### Step 3

> Then if you add `\n`, then we can break the message. like, `message : updated successfully \nDo you want to close or continue working with this`

---

I hope this answer will helps to someone

Comment: This works (Tested on PrimeNG 6). Step 1 wasn't necessary however.

Comment: Working great. I did actually just put the <br/> tag. Example: `text message <br/>`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is add **<pre></pre>** in confirm dialog to able use **\n**

For example:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
                    message: '<pre>CoC updated successfully\nDo you want to close or continue working with this?</pre>',
                    icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
                    header: 'Confirm Save',
                    accept: () => {
                       this.infomessage = [];
                        this.infomessage.push({ severity: 'success', summary: '', detail: Updated Successfully' });                    },
                    reject: () => {
                        this.router.navigate(['versions']);
                    }
                });
```

Source: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1310

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding `<pre></pre>` in the message like this. Moreover try using `\n` instead of `</br>`

```
message: '<pre>phrase 1\nphrase 2</pre>',
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that works but you could try to use the DomSanitizer. Modify your code like that:

```
message: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
'CoC updated successfully' + '</br>' + ' Do you want to close or continue working with this?'
)
```

Before you need that:

```
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

and in the constructor...

```
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)
```

When you look into the sourcecode of [PrimeNG](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog.ts)... they are using

```
[innerHTML]="message"
```

So that probably could work.

Comment: But am don't like to use `[innerHttml]`. I think it's bad idea. I'll try it for worst case :)

Comment: You don't have to. They do in their code to set the content of the dialog. I mentioned that because the DomSanitizer does not work without using [innerHTML].

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
message: 'phrase 1' + '<br>' + 'phrase 2',
```